# Where do I put custom packages in a directory structure for a large document?

Tags: compiling, package-writing, thesis

I am writing a large document (thesis proposal) that I would like to break into separate files, with the following directory structure:

```
.
|-- ch/
|   |-- chapter1.tex
|   |-- chapter2.tex
|   |-- somemacros.sty
|   |-- moremacros.sty
|
|-- main.tex
```

The `main.tex` file calls `\usepackage{ch/somemacros}`, which in turn requires the `moremacros` package.  Unfortunately, compiling this will fail to find `./moremacros.sty` because it simply doesn't exist there.

I hesitate to hard code the directory structure into the packages, since some of these macros are written for use outside of this particular document (e.g., subject-specific mathematical notation).  But i also hesitate to develop these macros in a separate VCS repository, since I'm developing them as needed while writing the proposal document.

How can I handle this problem?  Is there a solution that meets my constraints? Also feel free to (try to) convince me that these constraints are unnecessary (e.g., "use a better directory structure", "use a separate repository", etc.).

Comment: `\usepackage{ch/somemacros}` is wrong the argument should be a _name_ not a filepath. Just use `\usepackage{somemacros}` and make sure that `ch//` is in your `TEXINPUTS` then all directories below `ch` will be searched for files.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do I have to set `TEXINPUTS` globally, though?  That is, for every large project, I would need `ch//` in my `TEXINPUTS`?    I'd like to do this locally, if possible, so that things are modular.

Comment: One think to consider is to ensure that ALL .tex files are at the same hierarchy level (that is creata `main/main.tex` and then _always_ use relative paths `../ch/somemacros.sty`. Anyway, that is how I have been doing and seems to work great for me.

Comment: I don't follow the bit about the separate VCS repository. Why can't you just put them in your personal TEXMF tree?

Comment: @cfr Because I want the VCS to track changes to the macros *along with* changes to my writing, i.e., in the same history of changes.

Comment: @PeterGrill Thanks for the tip.  Unless someone has a different suggestion, I might follow yours.

Comment: On a unix based system, you could just symlink from your personal TEXMF tree. I don't know if there is a similar trick on Windows?

Comment: I *deliberately* separate out macros I use more generally from project development. (So I actually have 4 distinct VCS thingies going: three types of project (not three projects - three types) and then my TEXMF tree.) But obviously that wouldn't suit everyone.

Comment: it depends on your systenm on the linux commandline you can do `TEXINPUTS=ch: pdflatex main` for example and just set it for that one command, some editors will let you set it in a project for that document or  you could have a texmf.cnf file in the file with your main document and set tex settings there or...

Comment: @cfr Good point; I do use Windows, and I don't know if there is something similar to symlinks.  I'll look into it.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've never heard of `texmf.cnf` before; I'll need to look into that, but it sounds like what I want.

Comment: @HenryDeYoung  hmm seems you need to set an env variable to pick up a local texmf.cnf so no easier than setting texinputs, but I'll add a windows friendlier technique to the other question.

Comment: I added a description of `\input@path` to the linked answer.